# Is $\max(X) \geq E(X) + \sigma(X) \geq E(X) - \sigma(X) \geq \min(X)$ true?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Where $X$ is a discrete random variable with finite support, $E(X)$ its expectation, and $\sigma(X)$ the square root of the variance. $\min(X)$ and $\max(X)$ do not denote two random variables, but the maximum and minimum values that $X$ could obtain (i.e. for $X\sim \text{Unif}\lbrace{0, \dots, n\rbrace}$, $\min(X) = 0$, $\max(X) = n$.
I think this is true, but cannot come up with a proof. Does anybody have a counterexample or a proof?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How is $\sigma(X)$ defined? Can you get, from the definition, inequalities relating it to the maximum distance of a possible value of $X$ from ${\Bbb E}X$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your inequality chain is equivalent to
$$\min(X-E[X]) \leq -\sigma(X-E[X]) \leq \sigma(X-E[X])\leq \max(X-E[X]).$$ Do you think that is true?

Comment: Okay, it's false. Thanks for the help.